# Office Graph API - get items from list

Tags: sharepoint, office365

Is there a way within the Office Graph API to access items in a specific list - and not just items that I can see, but items I may not have access to?

Comment: Currently the Graph API doesn't allow access to SharePoint lists and libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Graph access to SharePoint objects is currently in the beta version of Graph. See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/sharepoint.

To access specific items, the endpoint pattern would be:
    GET https: //graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}

For example: https:// graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/mytenant.sharepoint.com:/sites/mysite:/Lists/Announcements/Items/1

As for being able to access items you do not have access to: No. That would be a horrible security problem if you could use any API to access such items.

Comment: This just get the meta data of the list item. If my list item is a json file say order.json then how can i get the content of the order.json

Comment: @Varadha31590: Yes, a list item is basically just metadata. A file, however, is not the same as a list item. In the SharePoint Object Model, a file is of type SPFile and an item is SPItem. To get the bytes of the file, simply place a GET request to the URL of the file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of permission for app registered on the Microsoft Azure platform.

One is delegated permission. In this scenario, the user delegates access to a client application. We can call the REST API to get the data owned by who sign in.

The another is Application-level. In this scenario which permits a web service (a confidential client) to use its own credentials to authenticate when calling another web service, instead of impersonating a user. For example, a service or daemon app can retrieve all the users in a tenant if it has the Read all users' full profiles permission selected in the Azure Management Portal. And we can get the specific user's drive via the API like below:

```
GET /users/<id | userPrincipalName>/drive
```

More detail about REST API for handling the files on OneDrive for business, please refer to link below:

https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/drive

And here is the link for the authentication protocols for the Azure AD support:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151124.aspx

Comment: This doesn't quite answer my question - looking for specific references or examples of how to get items from a list within SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't retrieve SharePoint list items using Graph API, but you can use **SharePoint REST API** for that. It's similar to Graph API and supports OAuth.

Check the documentation for SharePoint API here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To get items from a list within SharePoint, you can use SharePoint Rest API. A sample code to get items using rest api is as below:

```
// For SharePoint 2010
var strRestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/{{listname}}

// For Office 365 or SharePoint 203
var strRestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle({{listname}})/Items

$.ajax({
    url: strRestUrl,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function(response){
        // success callback function
    },
    complete: function(){
        // complete callback function
    },
    error: function (data) {
        // error callback function
        console.log(data.responseJSON.error);
    }
});
```

If you are using SharePoint 2010 then Rest URL is different and if you are using SharePoint 2013/Office 365 rest URL is different. Hope this code will help you.

More details about REST API are as available at below link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx